# Huge spacing when using "clear:both"?

Tags: css

I'm using so many styles that I don't know of a simple way to post it, but it's basically like this:

I have an image floating to the right and some text to the left. I tried adding "clear:both" to the H2 tags that separate the major text sections, but that went weird so I tried an HR tag instead (which also uses clear:both). In both cases I end up with a ridiculous amount of spacing which I didn't expect.

The page is here:

`http://www.goodpricescome.com/this_site.php`

You can see the weird spacing right after the first image/text section. Even in the inspector, I just don't see what's happening here.

Comment: Could you post the css and html please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#content` is not floated and its previous sibling `#sidebar` is floated. In this case, the clearing element inside `#content` takes `#sidebar` into account. Here is the expected result when (i) sidebar is shorter than pre-clear content (ii) sidebar is taller than pre-clear content:

```
content content content content sidebar sidebar
content content content content sidebar sidebar
content content content content content content 
content content content content content content 
----- clearing hr  ----

content content content content sidebar sidebar
content content content content sidebar sidebar
                                sidebar sidebar
                                sidebar sidebar
----- clearing hr  ----
```

Use one of the following solutions:

- preferably add `float: left` to `#content`
- add `overflow: hidden` to `#content`

Comment: Man that was quick... and it makes perfect sense too. Most importantly, it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) #sidebar is floated but #content is not floated hence you are getting so much space so you need to add `#content{ float: left; }`

2) as in #content you image is floated but p is not floated hence margin of HR is not taking effect hence best way here is on hr add `float:left` but keep `width: 100%` so it will cover full width of #content

**CSS**

```
#content{
float: left;
}

hr{
float: left;
width: 100%;
/*clear:both*/
}
```